# WPF style,visibility

Tags: wpf, styles, mouseevent, visibility, togglebutton

Now I have a `ToggleButton` style, then I set the `Chrome.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden` it seems like the `ToggleButton` hiddened, but it's not.

I use the snoop, find out the `ToggleButton's` `Visibility` is *visible*. How can I change the `ToggleButton's` visibility in style?

Here is the style:

```
 <Style x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle"
           TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
                Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}" />
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
                Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Padding"
                Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="go">
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5"
                                                        Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5"
                                                      Value="720" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5"
                                                      Value="0.15" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5"
                                                      Value="0.15" />
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Grid x:Name="grid"
                          RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform />
                                <SkewTransform />
                                <RotateTransform />
                                <TranslateTransform />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <Border x:Name="Chrome"
                                BorderThickness="5"
                                CornerRadius="10"
                                BorderBrush="#FFD7FF25"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                              RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                        </Border>
                        <Button x:Name="button"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Height="16.333"
                                Width="Auto"
                                Background="#FFD7FF25"
                                Foreground="#FFFF0B0B"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                BorderBrush="#FFD7FF25"
                                Padding="0,-6,0,0"
                                FontSize="16"
                                Margin="0,-4.167,-3.334,0"
                                Content="x"
                                Focusable="False"
                                Visibility="Collapsed"
                                Click="Button_OnClick"
                                BorderThickness="1" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                 Value="True"
                                 SourceName="grid">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                    TargetName="button"
                                    Value="Visible" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                    TargetName="Chrome"
                                    Value="#FF4DFF25" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                    TargetName="button"
                                    Value="#FF4DFF25" />
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    TargetName="button"
                                    Value="#FF4DFF25" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click"
                                      SourceName="button">
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="go_BeginStoryboard"
                                             Storyboard="{StaticResource go}" />
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                                 Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                    TargetName="Chrome"
                                    Value="Red" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                 Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="#ADADAD" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

When you mouseon, the `ToggleButton` will display a `Button` with `X`, click it, this `ToggleButton` will disappear.

*`Note:`* Put the `ToggleButton` in a `WrapPanel`, more than one, you can look a blank in the front of `WrapPanel`.

Comment: Please put some code about this problem.

Comment: I can't put picture.i edit togglebutton's content in style,now a grid is its root element,i change the grid's visibility in Style,but the togglebutton's visibility is not changed(I watch it in snoop(a spy++ for wpf)),it leaves a blank.I have no idea to set the togglebutton's visibility in Style.

Comment: I ran your example. There was a green button that, when you hover the red cross appeared. I click on the `X` toggle button has disappeared. You've the same work? If so, what should you do?

Comment: @Anatoliy Nikolaev thanks,you can do this,put the togglebutton in a wrappanel,more and more, click x to close it,you can look a blank space in the front of wrappanel

Comment: Well, this is normal behavior. There is a panel, have their buttons in it. You're hiding the button in its place there is an empty place. Do you want to *remove* the empty space to the hide button?

Comment: yes,do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can add setter of visibility like this..

```
 <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="hello" >
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">

        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

use thi on any button like this..

```
<Button Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource hello}}" Width="100" Background="Red" Height="100" />
```

hope this helps..for query plz comment below..

Comment: thanks,i am afraid you are not understand what i mean.I want to modify the togglebutton's visibility in click a button that in the togglebutton by a style.the other words, the button is in a togglebutton,it's function is close this togglebutton by set the togglebutton's visibility=Collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the animation works as it should, the `ToggleButton` disappears. But you want him to be disappearing from the panel (`WrapPanel`) released the place and the adjacent elements moved him.

Your example does not work because, in the animation you specify `Grid`:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid">
     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

and he, as we know, the good disappears. Physically, the `ToggleButton` is still in memory, so you just hid in the `Grid`, so the empty space you can see it.

You have to make the animation for all the `ToggleButtons`, then it will be as it should disappear and not leave empty space. That is, in the property `TargetName` specify itself `ToggleButton`. A simple example:

```
    <WrapPanel MinWidth="100" Width="200">
        <WrapPanel.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="MyButton1">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="MyButton1">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="MyButton2">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="MyButton2">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="MyButton3">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="MyButton3">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </WrapPanel.Triggers>

        <ToggleButton Name="MyButton1" Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle}" Width="30" Height="30" />
        <ToggleButton Name="MyButton2" Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle}" Width="30" Height="30" />
        <ToggleButton Name="MyButton3" Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonStyle}" Width="30" Height="30" />            
    </WrapPanel>
```